# How to install node.js version 10 on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: apt, nodejs, npm

I am trying to install node.js version10 on my ubuntu 18.04 but it is always installing version 8.10. I have tried different links.
I have tried the following commands:

```
$ sudo curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | sudo -E bash -
```

> ### Installing the NodeSource Node.js 10.x repo...
>
> ### Populating apt-get cache...
>
> - apt-get update Hit:1 http://linux.teamviewer.com/deb stable InRelease Hit:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
>   Hit:3 https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian stable InRelease
>   Hit:4 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic InRelease
>   Hit:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/deadsnakes/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease
>   Get:6 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease
>   [88.7 kB]     Get:7 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates
>   InRelease [88.7 kB]    Hit:8
>   http://ppa.launchpad.net/ethereum/ethereum/ubuntu bionic InRelease
>   Get:9 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease
>   [74.6 kB]  Ign:10 http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian
>   18.04 InRelease         Hit:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/maarten-baert/simplescreenrecorder/ubuntu
>   bionic InRelease Hit:12
>   http://ppa.launchpad.net/wireshark-dev/stable/ubuntu bionic InRelease
>   Err:13 http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian 18.04 Release
>   404  Not Found [IP: 23.40.180.94 80] Reading package lists... Done E:
>   The repository 'http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian 18.04
>   Release' does not have a Release file. N: Updating from such a
>   repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by
>   default. N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user
>   configuration details. Error executing command, exiting

```
@lc2530hz:~$ sudo apt install nodejs
```

> Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree        Reading
> state information... Done nodejs is already the newest version
> (8.10.0~dfsg-2ubuntu0.4). The following packages were automatically
> installed and are no longer required:   gyp libjs-async libjs-inherits
> libjs-node-uuid libssl1.0-dev libuv1-dev   libwireshark11 libwiretap8
> libwscodecs2 libwsutil9 Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them. 0
> upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 259 not upgraded.

But I am always getting version 8.10:

```
lc2530hz:~$ node -v
```

> v8.10.0 @lc2530hz:~$

Somebody please guide.
Zulfi.

Answer (score 3):

I am using `nvm` to switch between nodejs versions.
https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm
Install nvm:
`curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.35.3/install.sh | bash`
restart terminal
Install node 10.x:
`nvm install 10`
Switch to node 10.x:
`nvm use 10`
Check node version:
`node -v`